# Postgres: Selecting Distinct on a column is not returning distinct results with Joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm building a system in which there are the following tables:

- Song
- Broadcast
- Station
- Follow
- User

A user follows stations, which have songs on them through broadcasts.

I'm building a "feed" of songs for a user based on the stations they follow.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("broadcasts"."created_at", "songs"."id") songs.*
FROM "songs"
INNER JOIN "broadcasts" ON "songs"."shared_id" = "broadcasts"."song_id"
INNER JOIN "stations" ON "broadcasts"."station_id" = "stations"."id"
INNER JOIN "follows" ON "stations"."id" = "follows"."station_id"
WHERE "follows"."user_id" = 2
ORDER BY broadcasts.created_at desc
LIMIT 18
```

As you can see here, I'm getting duplicate songs which is happening because I'm following two stations that BOTH have broadcasted that same song:

[image: sql not working distinct on join]

Note: shared_id is the same as id.

My question is: **How do I modify this query so it will return only unique songs based on their id (or shared_id)?**

Comment: What happens if you return `"broadcasts"."created_at"` in the `SELECT`?

Comment: No change, I just get that value returned as well.

Comment: Sorry I should have added to my first comment: Is the returned created_at unique on every row?

Comment: Yea it is, I only have it in the distinct because I am using it in in the order, but its not a problem as its pretty much (totally?) impossible for two songs to have the same exact time anyway.

Comment: That's exactly the issue.  You're selecting distinct on a field that is pretty much guaranteed to be unique.  You should probably remove that from the distinct clause.

Comment: Ah ok, I do need to order by broadcasts.created_at so I've created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371656/order-by-join-column-but-use-distinct-on-another

Comment: BTW I needed it in the distinct clause so I could order it by that.  I did a little check and the duplicate broadcasts actually have the exact same created_at timestamp!  Because they are broadcast at the same time and the timestamp is stored by rails (so by the second rather than millisecond)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `"broadcasts"."created_at"` from the `DISTINCT` predicate because it is returning non-unique values, hence duplicate `songs`. If you need to use this information to sort please create a new question.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the point of my question but I've posted a revised question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371656/order-by-join-column-but-use-distinct-on-another