# Order by join column but use distinct on another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm building a system in which there are the following tables:

- Song
- Broadcast
- Station
- Follow
- User

A user follows stations, which have songs on them through broadcasts.

I'm building a "feed" of songs for a user based on the stations they follow.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("broadcasts"."created_at", "songs"."id") songs.*
FROM "songs"
INNER JOIN "broadcasts" ON "songs"."shared_id" = "broadcasts"."song_id"
INNER JOIN "stations" ON "broadcasts"."station_id" = "stations"."id"
INNER JOIN "follows" ON "stations"."id" = "follows"."station_id"
WHERE "follows"."user_id" = 2
ORDER BY broadcasts.created_at desc
LIMIT 18
```

[image: sql not working distinct on join]

Note: shared_id is the same as id.

As you can see I'm getting duplicate results, which I don't want.  I found out from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370422/postgres-selecting-distinct-on-a-column-is-not-returning-distinct-results-with) that this was due to selecting distinct on broadcasts.created_at.

My question is: How do I modify this query so it will return only unique songs based on their id **but still order by broadcasts.created_at**?

Comment: Something I just checked into: Songs are broadcast to multiple stations at the *exact* same time.  If you follow stations that are both getting a song broadcasted at the same time, those broadcasts have the exact same timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT a.maxcreated, b.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT bb.song_id, MAX(bb.created_at) AS maxcreated
        FROM follows aa
        INNER JOIN broadcasts bb ON aa.station_id = bb.station_id
        WHERE aa.user_id = 2
        GROUP BY bb.song_id
    ) a
INNER JOIN songs b ON a.song_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.maxcreated DESC
LIMIT 18
```

The `FROM` subselect retrieves distinct `song_id`s that are broadcasted by all stations the user follows; it also gets the latest broadcast date associated with each song. We have to encase this in a subquery because we have to `GROUP BY` on the columns we're selecting from, and we only want the unique `song_id` and the maxdate regardless of the station.

We then join that result in the outer query to the `songs` table to get the song information associated with each unique `song_id`

Comment: Fantastic.  Had to change b.song_id to b.id, but that worked!  I figured nested queries where the only solution, just am a novice with SQL in general.  Thanks!  If you can edit that one little thing I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Woops, forgot about that. Edited. Glad to hear it worked. Will provide explanation later as well.

Comment: Actually, I also just realized that there is no need to join the songs table in the sub-select. I edited the answer to take that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) if you want a cleaner query (nested queries make things harder to read)

I would look like this:

```
WITH a as (
        SELECT bb.song_id, MAX(bb.created_at) AS maxcreated
        FROM follows aa
        INNER JOIN broadcasts bb ON aa.station_id = bb.station_id
        INNER JOIN songs cc ON bb.song_id = cc.shared_id
        WHERE aa.user_id = 2
        GROUP BY bb.song_id
    )
SELECT
    a.maxcreated,
    b.*
FROM a INNER JOIN
    songs b ON a.song_id = b.id
ORDER BY
    a.maxcreated DESC
LIMIT 18
```

Using a CTE offers the advantages of improved readability and ease in maintenance of complex queries. The query can be divided into separate, simple, logical building blocks. These simple blocks can then be used to build more complex, interim CTEs until the final result set is generated.

Comment: Ah, hadn't heard of them but very cool.  Selected the other answer, but am using this as it is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding `GROUP BY Songs.id`

Comment: Once I add GROUP BY it forces me to group every column I'm selecting, how do I avoid that?

Comment: I think you cant avoid this in sql server and sql AnyWhere . Then the only solution is to remove broadcasts.created_at from DISTINCT

Comment: Well my question still remains, "How do I modify this query so it will return only unique songs based on their id but still order by broadcasts.created_at?".  Removing that from distinct still presents the same problem, and grouping them is not an option unless I can still select all the information..

Comment: You just have to do `MAX(broadcasts.created_at)` in your order by. I'll create an answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar query I was doing between `listens`, `tracks` and `albums` and it took me a long while to figure it out (hours).

If you use a `GROUP_BY songs.id`, you can get it to work by ordering by `MAX(broadcasts.created_at) DESC`.

Here's what the full SQL looks like:

```
SELECT songs.* FROM "songs"
INNER JOIN "broadcasts" ON "songs"."shared_id" = "broadcasts"."song_id"
INNER JOIN "stations" ON "broadcasts"."station_id" = "stations"."id"
INNER JOIN "follows" ON "stations"."id" = "follows"."station_id"
WHERE "follows"."user_id" = 2
GROUP BY songs.id
ORDER BY MAX(broadcasts.created_at) desc
LIMIT 18;
```